# Can access ssh, cannot access from browser

Tags: configuration, port, apache2, port-forwarding, ubuntu-16.04

straight to the question, i was been provided a server by our clients with ip x.x.x.x port 2215 to access it by ssh. Therefore i upload all my website to /var/www/html folder. Because i lack of knowledge in server, i tried to access it through browser by entering x.x.x.x:2215 but it returned an error "x.x.x.x has sent an invalid response".

Can anybody point out what is the causal of this? Whether it's server config problem or port forwarding issues, so that i can argue this to my client. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't connect to SSH and HTTP on the same port. The HTTPd has it's own port. Try it without the port for the default ports, if that doesn't work contact your client.

Comment: If i entered the ip only, it shows another website. My client using different port to redirect to different machine that serves the web page. Example when i access port 80, it shows websiteA, port 210 websiteB. So that i only given access on port 2215 (ssh) and my client said "It's up to you whatever you wanna do with the server". Where can i set so that when i open x.x.x.x:2215 it will shows the /var/www/html content? Is it possible through apache config or it's by my client port forwarding rules?

Comment: It all depends on the configuration of your web server. Share the configuration details, the logs, etc. It seems like you are in way over your head. Hire a consultant to sort things out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general two different services can’t run on the same TCP port.

The web server will be running on a different port than the one ssh uses, so pointing your web browser at `http://x.x.x.x:2215`  was the wrong thing to do.

I would start by simply connecting to the default http port,  `http://x.x.x.x` and then if that doesn’t show any content , then  simply confirm to the client that you have uploaded the content and ask how to proceed from there ...

Comment: If i entered the ip only, it shows another website. My client using different port to redirect to different machine that serves the web page. Example when i access port 80, it shows websiteA, port 210 websiteB. So that i only given access on port 2215 and my client said "It's up to you whatever you wanna do with the server". Where can i set so that when i open x.x.x.x:2215 it will shows the /var/www/html content? Is it possible through apache config or it's by my client port forwarding rules? I already asked my client but he's answer is more like challenging me instead of helping